# Motherboard requirements to enable 144hz wih integrated GPU

Tags: motherboard, resolution, integrated-graphics, refresh-rate, amd-ryzen

I am going to build a desktop based on "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2400G with Radeon™ RX Vega 11 Graphics". It has integrated video, so the monitor is going to be connected directly to the motherboard via DisplayPort.

The monitor is supposed to be one of 27" with 2560x1440 @ 144hz and Freesync.

Most motherboards I checked have something like *"Supports DisplayPort 1.2 with max. resolution 4096 x 2160 @ 60 Hz"*, and no information about lower resolutions at higher refresh rate.

So, is it safe to assume that 2560x1440 @ 144hz is equal amount of data per second as 4096x2160 @ 60hz, or do I have to find a motherboard that supports my specific resolution at specific refresh rate?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of bandwidth, I found the following:

> DisplayPort version 1.2 can support video resolutions of up to 3840 x
>   2160 pixels (4K) at a refresh rate of 60Hz, and it supports all common
>   3D video formats. In terms of bandwidth, **it can manage 17.28Gbps**

That being said, some back-of-the-napkin calculations using https://k.kramerav.com/support/bwcalculator.asp returns the following:

`Bandwidth Per Channel = 5.31 Gbps`

`Total Signal Bandwidth = 15.93 Gbps`

For all intents and purposes, technically, yes, that motherboard will support your resolution at that specified refresh rate.  Caveat emptor, you still have to consider equipment / cabling compatibility.  From a mathematical standpoint, you're on solid ground.